# webelement and driver has squiggly lines under it all of a sudden

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm using selenium and Java in Eclipse and all of a sudden I am checking my code and I see squiggly lines under the driver and webelements.  I tried hovering over it and checking to see if it would add anything but I didn't see anything that made a clear indication of what would fix it.

[image]

It seems like there is something wrong with the selenium dependencies if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: have you tried clean... project?

Comment: What do you mean by "clean... project"?  I have other projects that are using driver and WebElement and this project didn't have these in it before.  I'm not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have faced that kind of behavior quite a lot in past.

If you go to `Project -> Clean... -> Select your project and then hit clean`,

should help you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you would provide the error log either way.

1. First thing you shoud do is try to reload project.
2. Make sure to have proper dependencies provided with proper versions.

The Selenium dependency shoud look like this (for Java):

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
     <version>3.141.59</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

3. Check if the actual imports in this class are coming from the library that you're expecting to. There is a chance that you're not and then just remove that incorrect import and import it from correct class that you want.
4. Also, check if you don't have duplicates inside your project management file.